# Yii - How to verify if data doesn't exist

Tags: php, yii

How to verify if data in DB doesn't exists ?

As I know yii have a function is verify data exists, following code:

```
if(Register::model()->exists('email = :email', array(":email"=>$txtpemail))){
     print_r("Already Exist !");
}
```

So, is there any function for no exists data ? **OR** maybe have other suggestion to do that ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the negation in front of the exists method

```
if(!Register::model()->exists('email = :email', array(":email"=>$txtpemail))){
     print_r("Not Exist !");
}
```

Some other ways are

using exists() method

[click me!! for official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#exists-detail)

```
$existCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
$existCriteria->condition = 'email=:email';
$existCriteria->params = array(':email'=>$txtpemail);
if (!Register::model()->exists($existCriteria )) {
    $message = 'Not Exist !';
} else {
    $message = 'Already Exist !';
}
```

using find() method

[click me!! for official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#find-detail)

```
$findCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
$findCriteria->condition = 'email=:email';
$findCriteria->params = array(':email'=>$txtpemail);
if (Register::model()->find($findCriteria ) == null) {
    $message = 'Not Exist !';
} else {
    $message = 'Already Exist !';
}
```

Comment: If it is solved please accept the answer by clicking tick mark just below the vote down button this will help full to others too even its a basic thing.

Comment: yes ... i know but stackoverflow alert me have to wait 8 min